# Why is that when drop oil in a pot of heated water, that the oil globules form near perfect circles?

Tags: fluid-dynamics

I noticed this while I was cooking pasta:

[image]

The oil forms globules which viewed from top to down seem as perfect circles floating on the surface of water. How does this happen? Is there some elegant physics explanation behind this?

Comment: [Surface tension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surface_tension). Surfaces cost energy because the molecules there are poorly satisfied relative to the bulk, so surface area generally tends to minimize spontaneously.